# UDID for provisioning profile is 41 chars long and is not taken

Tags: ios, iphone

Hi we got a UDID that is 41 character long from client and that UDID is not adding on apple developer-> device.
I try to add the UDID but apple automatically remove last character.
let me know if anyone have encounter same issue.
In below attachment there is no device info and it may treat as corrupted device
[image]

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27192630/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR this question is totally different that not got solving my problem

Answer (score 0):

It should exactly have **40** characters not **41**.

Comment: Yeah i know that but we got 41 character long udid from client

Comment: developer portal can validate. Have you tried that?

Comment: i added the udid and the last characters is automatically remove and as you can see it added to developer portal device list but device info is not showing