# C# Regex for Guid

Tags: c#, regex

I need to parse through a string and add single quotes around each Guid value.  I was thinking I could use a Regex to do this but I'm not exactly a Regex guru.

Is there a good Regex to use to identify a Guid?

My second question is once I've found a valid regex I'm assuming I would use `Regex.Replace(String, String, MatchEvaluator)` but I'm not quite sure of the syntax. Maybe something like:

```
return Regex.Replace(stringToFindMatch, GuidRegex, match =>
{
    return string.Format("'{0}'", match.Groups[0].ToString());
});
```

A string that I'm trying to parse may look like this:

> "SELECT
>                                           passwordco0_.PASSWORD_CONFIG_ID as PASSWORD1_46_0_,
>                                       FROM
>                                           PASSWORD_CONFIG passwordco0_ 
>                                       WHERE
>                                           passwordco0_.PASSWORD_CONFIG_ID=baf04077-a3c0-454b-ac6f-9fec00b8e170;
>                                       @p0 = baf04077-a3c0-454b-ac6f-9fec00b8e170 [Type: Guid (0)]"

Comment: That is SQL, and you should be using SQL parameters.

Comment: Why would you use REgex there is a GUID.IsGUid

Comment: Actually, there is a parameter, but its the same as the value in the where clause. Where is this coming from? A profiler?

Comment: @jrummell This is coming from a profiler yeah.  I'm trying to convert the output such that I can copy and paste it and run it in SQL Management Studio.  This is for logging purposes only.  It will still be ran as parametrized sql.

Comment: Which profiler? There might be a way to modify the output. MiniProfiler, for example, has an EF specific formatter that generates SSMS friendly sql.

Comment: @jrummel It's a custom log4net appender.  This output is being generated by NHibernate.  The custom log4net appender is based on this one: http://gedgei.wordpress.com/2011/09/03/logging-nhibernate-queries-with-parameters/

Comment: @MicahArmantrout - RegEx can be helpful when testing with NUnit or other situations where a RegEx is accepted as an argument to another routine that does the string comparison.  For example:  StringAssert.IsMatch("[a-f0-9]{8}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{4}-[a-f0-9]{12}", MyInstance.GUID);

Comment: @MicahArmantrout Is there?! My intellisense claims that there's no *IsGuid* in the *Guid* class...

Comment: Guess in was wrong  I out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Micah Armantrout - I want a regex so I can do client side validation before submittal. I can't use the GUID methods in my regular expression validator.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131143/javascript-string-to-guid or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368381/regular-expression-retrieve-the-guid-inside-parenthesis

Answer (score 238, accepted):

This one is quite simple and does not require a delegate as you say.

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
     @"(?im)^[{(]?[0-9A-F]{8}[-]?(?:[0-9A-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}[)}]?$", 
     "'$0'");
```

This matches the following styles, which are all equivalent and acceptable formats for a GUID.

```
ca761232ed4211cebacd00aa0057b223
CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223
{CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223}
(CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223)
```

**Update 1**

@NonStatic makes the point in the comments that the above regex will match false positives which have a wrong closing delimiter.

This can be avoided by regex conditionals which are broadly supported.

Conditionals are supported by the JGsoft engine, Perl, PCRE, Python, and the .NET framework. 
Ruby supports them starting with version 2.0. Languages such as Delphi, PHP, and R that 
have regex features based on PCRE also support conditionals. (source http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html)

The regex that follows Will match

```
{123}
(123)
123
```

And will not match

```
{123)
(123}
{123
(123
123}
123)
```

Regex:

```
^({)?(\()?\d+(?(1)})(?(2)\))$
```

The solutions is simplified to match only numbers to show in a more clear way what is required if needed.

Comment: As written, this would not have worked for all of the valid types of GUIDs (hence the update).

Comment: This does not account for lower case characters which would be a valid case. Use ^[{|\(]?[0-9a-fA-F]{8}[-]?([0-9a-fA-F]{4}[-]?){3}[0-9a-fA-F]{12}[\)|}]?$ or use the /i flag

Comment: @MichaelBrown It does match case insensitive, see RegexOptions.IgnoreCase in the code sample.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not fully right: "{CA761232-ED42-11CE-BACD-00AA0057B223)" will be accepted as well but you know it is not a right one.

Comment: @NonStatic Yes that's right. If needed you can use my update 1 to prevent this false positive

Comment: @buckley Does your update 1 solution match `{(123)}` ? If yes could be not correct consider it a Guid...

Comment: @AntonioManello {(123)} is not matched as it is not a correct GUID. The update was for cases where the starting delimiter differs from the ending delimiter

Comment: Was looking for something that could be used to identify only valid Guids. Building off of this answer, this is the solution that ended up working for me: `^({)?(?(1)|(\()?)[0-9A-F]{8}(-)?([0-9A-F]{4}(?(3)-)){3}[0-9A-F]{12}(?(1)}|(?(2)\)))$`

Comment: The regex will also allow less than 4 minus signs. Fyi for those who care about this. For those who don't care, here is a simpler regex that allows many more false positives: `[0-9a-fA-F\-]{32,36}`.

Comment: @usr Matching guids with less than 4 minus signs is a consequence of allowing a guid with no minus signs at all and writing a regex that's (relatively) small. Using alternation (pipe | symbol) makes it possible to write out the different cases. That will make the regex longer and, arguably, more readable in addition to addressing not mixing delimiters without regex conditionals.

Comment: Doesn't work for `https://support.office.com/en-us/article/poisson-function-d81f7294-9d7c-4f75-bc23-80aa8624173a`

Comment: That's because the regex matches guids that stand on their own on 1 line (and not part of something else like and url)

Comment: For some reason doesn't work on this GUID: f150ab2e-c5ab-4b89-9ab7-77da01243190

Comment: @Farlock85 That's because the api that I use (.net) is told to ignore the case. Your guid is in lowercase. Can you tell your api to ignore the case as well?

Answer (score 72):

Most basic regex is following:

```
(^([0-9A-Fa-f]{8}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{4}[-]?[0-9A-Fa-f]{12})$)
```

or you could [paste it here](https://regex101.com/r/GMdKKR/1).

Hope this saves you some time.

Comment: Not quite as full as the suggested answer, but +1 for the regex101.com link.

Comment: Removed the repetition: `[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-){3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}` The dashes could be made optional: `[0-9A-Fa-f]{8}-?([0-9A-Fa-f]{4}-?){3}[0-9A-Fa-f]{12}`.

Comment: @LouisSomers the group can be made non-capturing by adding `?:` after the opening parentheses.

Answer (score 37):

For C# .Net to find and replace any guid looking string from the given text,

Use this RegEx:

```
[({]?[a-fA-F0-9]{8}[-]?([a-fA-F0-9]{4}[-]?){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}[})]?
```

Example C# code:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(
      source, 
      @"[({]?[a-fA-F0-9]{8}[-]?([a-fA-F0-9]{4}[-]?){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}[})]?", 
      @"${ __UUID}", 
      RegexOptions.IgnoreCase
);
```

Surely works! And it matches & replaces the following styles, which are all equivalent and acceptable formats for a GUID.

```
"aa761232bd4211cfaacd00aa0057b243" 
"AA761232-BD42-11CF-AACD-00AA0057B243" 
"{AA761232-BD42-11CF-AACD-00AA0057B243}" 
"(AA761232-BD42-11CF-AACD-00AA0057B243)"
```

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me but this one did!

Comment: One problem here. Guid will only contain hexadecimal numbers. Thus letters from a-z and A-Z are not acceptable but only a-f and A-F. Otherwise it would accept any text with 32 characters as a valid Guid.

Comment: Ditto - The accepted answer did not work for me but this one did!

Comment: You set `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` - because of this [a-f0-9] would be enough.

Comment: Yup, agree, ignored removing it as it doesn't hurt. IgnoreCase was placed in for initial answer and then I added [a-f0-9] in regex if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 10):

You can easily auto-generate the C# code using: http://regexhero.net/tester/.

Its free.

Here is how I did it:

[image]

The website then auto-generates the .NET code:

```
string strRegex = @"\b[A-F0-9]{8}(?:-[A-F0-9]{4}){3}-[A-F0-9]{12}\b";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"     {CD73FAD2-E226-4715-B6FA-14EDF0764162}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg =         Debug|x64";
string strReplace = @"""$0""";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Comment: I'd also include lower-case characters with `a-f` to ensure lower-cased GUIDs are also supported.

Answer (score 9):

In .NET Framework 4 there is enhancement System.Guid structure, These includes new TryParse and TryParseExact methods to Parse GUID.
Here is example for this.

```
    //Generate New GUID
    Guid objGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
    //Take invalid guid format
    string strGUID = "aaa-a-a-a-a";

    Guid newGuid;

    if (Guid.TryParse(objGuid.ToString(), out newGuid) == true)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("<br/>{0} is Valid GUID.", objGuid.ToString()));
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("<br/>{0} is InValid GUID.", objGuid.ToString()));
    }


    Guid newTmpGuid;

    if (Guid.TryParse(strGUID, out newTmpGuid) == true)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("<br/>{0} is Valid GUID.", strGUID));
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("<br/>{0} is InValid GUID.", strGUID));
    }
```

In this example we create new guid object and also take one string variable which has invalid guid. After that we use TryParse method to validate that both variable has valid guid format or not. By running example you can see that string variable has not valid guid format and it gives message of "InValid guid". If string variable has valid guid than this will return true in TryParse method.

Comment: The question was asking how to find/extract a GUID from a longer string, not validate a GUID. Suggest you remove this answer.

Comment: @Micah Armantrout: It may be a "good" answer, but it is not an answer for *this question*. If you just put any answer anywhere you like, it kind of defeats the purpose of StackOverflow :)

Comment: Well, for someone like me searching for a "regex for guid", this answer was really the most helpful - I don't __really__ need a regex, I need to match GUIDs, and this page is the first result for "regex to detect guid" on Google currently.

Comment: Seconding @Dan Field.  I came here on a searching for regex for guid and found this answer to be what I really wanted.  The purpose of StackOverflow was thus fulfilled.

Comment: This is not the relevant answer but it of course is helpful. One vote from me. :)

Answer (score 7):

I use an easier regex pattern

```
^[0-9A-Fa-f\-]{36}$
```

Comment: This will match more than GUIDs

Comment: ... and it will only match for lines only containing Guid and nothing else.

Answer (score 7):

To simply match GUID's with hyphens like these:
`63F0DA57-5AA2-4271-B9DE-6FD68008EA98`
`aa76ae52-14f2-5774-A645-9d002a72dec1`

I use the following:

```
[a-fA-F\d]{8}-[a-fA-F\d]{4}-[a-fA-F\d]{4}-[a-fA-F\d]{4}-[a-fA-F\d]{12}
```

Comment: This is the cleanest one (results wise) out of all.