# Javascript string to Guid

Tags: javascript, string, uuid, guid

in javascript, what is the easiest way to convert this string

```
798205486e954fa880a0b366e6725f71
```

to GUID format like this

```
79820548-6e95-4fa8-80a0-b366e6725f71
```

this is the messy way I do it :) im looking for the cleanest way

```
var employeeId = shift.employee.id.substring(0, 8) + "-" + shift.employee.id.substring(8, 12)
                    + "-" + shift.employee.id.substring(12, 16) + "-" + shift.employee.id.substring(16, 20) + "-" + shift.employee.id.substring(20, 32);
```

Comment: I am just looking if any that exist natively... i can do it with string manipulation.. but I was thinking if theres clean way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did it in string manipulation

```
var str = "798205486e954fa880a0b366e6725f71";
var parts = [];
parts.push(str.slice(0,8));
parts.push(str.slice(8,12));
parts.push(str.slice(12,16));
parts.push(str.slice(16,20));
parts.push(str.slice(20,32));
var GUID = parts.join('-'); 

console.log(GUID) // prints expected GUID
```

I did it this way because I don't like inserting characters between strings. If there is any problem tell me.

Or you could use a `for` loop like bellow

```
var str = "798205486e954fa880a0b366e6725f71";
var lengths = [8,4,4,4,12];
var parts = [];
var range = 0; 
for (var i = 0; i < lengths.length; i++) {
    parts.push(str.slice(range,range+lengths[i]));
    range += lengths[i];
};
var GUID = parts.join('-');
console.log(GUID);
```

Answer (score 12):

Cleanest way?

Shortest:

```
var txt = shift.employee.id;
txt.replace(/([0-z]{8})([0-z]{4})([0-z]{4})([0-z]{4})([0-z]{12})/,"$1-$2-$3-$4-$5");
//"79820548-6e95-4fa8-80a0-b366e6725f71"
```

or if you don't care about the acceptable characters, it can be be even shorter (and cleaner):

```
txt.replace(/(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})/,"$1-$2-$3-$4-$5");  //boom!
```

Some don't like using regex for everything, but I liked it.

Answer (score 6):

You could use an regular expression:

```
var rxGetGuidGroups = /(\w{8})(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{4})(\w{12})/,
    employeeId = shift.employee.id.replace(rxGetGuidGroups, '$1-$2-$3-$4-$5');
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/mHL26/)

Answer (score 4):

Try this function, It will return string in GUID format

```
function getGuid(str){
return str.slice(0,8)+"-"+str.slice(8,12)+"-"+str.slice(12,16)+
"-"+str.slice(16,20)+"-"+str.slice(20,str.length+1)
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Or you would try-

```
var guid = (function () {
    function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
               .toString(16)
               .substring(1);
    }
    return function () {
        return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
           s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
    };
})();
```

**Where** 
Your new guid be like-

```
var newGuid= guid();
```

newGuid returns-  `7d4b3ef0-b5bb-5c42-2a02-80a4371babf8`

Comment: The question is how to parse an existing guid. Not how to generate a new guid.

Comment: This solution does not always generate a valid `guid` as some bits of a guid have to be set to a specific value, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Format