# Javascript: GUID: RegEx: string to GUID

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a textbox that a user can paste into using Ctrl+V. I would like to restrict the textbox to accept just GUIDs. I tried to write a small function that would format an input string to a GUID based on RegEx, but I can't seem to be able to do it. I tried following the below post:
[Javascript string to Guid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131143/javascript-string-to-guid)

```
function stringToGUID()
{
    var strInput = 'b6b954d9cbac4b18b0d5a0f725695f1ca98d64e456f76';
    var strOutput = strInput.replace(/([0-f]{8})([0-f]{4})([0-f]{4})([0-f]{4})([0-f]{12})/,"$1-$2-$3-$4-$5");
    console.log(strOutput );
    //from my understanding, the input string could be any sequence of 0-9 or a-f of any length and a valid giud patterened string would be the result in the above code. This doesn't seem to be the case;
    //I would like to extract first 32 characters; how do I do that?

}
```

Comment: _" I can't seem to be able to do it"_ - why is that? What issues are you running into?

Comment: From my understanding, the regex pattern I'm using would not only find a guid, but also extract only first 32 alphanumerics. That doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: Could the user paste in a GUID with the hyphens already included?

Comment: You need `[0-9a-fA-F]` for a hex character.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, yes. The user could copy and paste a valid guid or paste/type in a where clause that could potentially crash my database. My effort is to allow the user to type in a guid.

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper In that case, you need to remove the hyphens before further processing the string.

Comment: That could potentially crash your database? Please read about SQL injection.

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze, thank you for your suggestion. I'll look it up. I have added a "keyDown" event listener where I allow an alphanumeric with a -(hyphen).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you remove the dashes, truncate to 32 characters, and then test if the remaining characters are valid before inserting the dashes:

```
function stringToGUID()
{
    var input = 'b6b954d9cbac4b18b0d5a0f725695f1ca98d64e456f76';
    let g = input.replace("-", "");
    g = g.substring(0, 32);
    if (/^[0-9A-F]{32}$/i.test(g)) {
        g = g.replace(/(.{8})(.{4})(.{4})(.{4})(.{12})/, "$1-$2-$3-$4-$5");
    }
    console.log(g);
}

stringToGUID();
```

(The `i` at the end of the regex makes it case-insensitive.)

Comment: @SoftwareDveloper I simplified the regex for the replace as it is already known that all the characters are valid.

Answer (score 0):

You are already matching 32 characters with the pattern, so there is no need to get a separate operation to get 32 characters to test against.

You can replace all the hyphens with an empty string, and then match the pattern from the start of the string using `^`

Then first check if there is a match, and if there is do the replacement with the 5 groups and hyphens in between. If there is not match, return the original string.

The function `stringToGUID()` by itself does not do anything except log a string that is hardcoded in the function. To extend its functionality, you can pass a parameter.

```js
function stringToGUID(s) {
  const regex = /^([0-f]{8})([0-f]{4})([0-f]{4})([0-f]{4})([0-f]{12})/;
  const m = s.replace(/-+/g, '').match(regex);
  return m ? `${m[1]}-${m[2]}-${m[3]}-${m[4]}-${m[5]}` : s;
}

[
  'b6b954d9cbac4b18b0d5a0f725695f1ca98d64e456f76',
  'b6b954d9-cbac-4b18-b0d5-a0f725695f1c',
  '----54d9cbac4b18b0d5a0f725695f1ca98d64e456f76',
  '!@#$%'
].forEach(s => {
  console.log(stringToGUID(s));
});
```