# Get matching strings in a variable

Tags: powershell

I am trying to fetch the matching strings from a variable.

For example,

```
$out = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{F1E1501C-B95C-42E0-BFD4-757DF1B961D1}"
```

I need the value inside `"{ }"`.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why hasn't it worked as needed? Do you know you could use regular expressions to get the desired result?

Comment: ... or `-split` or ...

Comment: @Olaf I am new to power shell, I have googled so far, how to use regular expression, can you explain

$out = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  select-string -pattern "zTPFGI"

@{UninstallString=RunDll32 C:\PROGRA~2\COMMON~1\INSTAL~1\engine\6\INTEL3~1\Ctor.dll,LaunchSetup "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{F1E1501C-B95C-42E0-BFD4-757DF1B961D1}\setup.exe" -l0x9  FromAddRemove; Display
Name=zTPFGI; LogFile=C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{F1E1501C-B95C-42E0-BFD4-757DF1B961D1}\setup.ilg}

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers

Comment: @jerry You should add this explanation to your actual question. There it would even possible to format it nicely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a RegEx for this:

```
$out = "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{F1E1501C-B95C-42E0-BFD4-757DF1B961D1}"

$out -match "^.*{(?<guid>.*)}$" | Out-Null
```

You can then access the value like this:

```
$matches.Guid
```

`-match` produces a bool that lets you know if it was successful or not.  Here I discard it by sending it to `Out-Null`, but you can use it to decide if you should proceeed, by, say, wrapping it in an `if`:

```
if ($out -match "^.*{(?<guid>.*)}$")
{
   # Do something
}
```

Note that you can get a more accurate match for the GUID using the patterns mentioned here:

[RegEx for GUID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040707/c-sharp-regex-for-guid)

Comment: $out = Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* |  select-string -pattern "zTPFGI"
i dont know the GUID i have used the above command to get the GUID

Comment: @jerry Please re-read the answer. `(?<foo>...)` is regular expression syntax for a named capturing group, so you can access the group by name (`$matches['foo']` or `$matches.foo`) rather than by index (`$matches[1]`).