# Extract a GUID from a string. How can I do it?

Tags: c#, guid

I have a string in this format:

```
"object": "Board-f330c10a-a9eb-4253-b554-43ed95c87242"
```

and I want to extract guid from it.I was trying like this:

```
Guid.Parse(followActivity.Object.Split('-').Skip(1).FirstOrDefault());
```

but it takes only the first part of the guid string. How can I extract whole guid?

Can anybody help.

Comment: Use a regex that matches GUIDs, for instance the one here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11040707/c-sharp-regex-for-guid

Comment: are you sure, every input should contain `Board-` or something like that before a `GUID`

Comment: @sujithkarivelil Yup. Every string is like **Board-f330c10a-a9eb-4253-b554-43ed95c87242**

Comment: Your code is saying "split on dashes, then ignore the first item, and give me the next item". You should be putting it back together piece-by-piece.

Comment: Thanks all. All the answers amd comments are helpful. Got the issue solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like [this Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/tx9Cf4) , if every input follows the same patter like `Board-`:

```
string complexGuid = "Board-f330c10a-a9eb-4253-b554-43ed95c87242";
string extractedGuid = complexGuid.Substring(complexGuid.IndexOf('-') +1 );
```

Here `complexGuid.IndexOf('-')` will return the first index of the `'-'` which is the `-` after the `Board` in the given example. we need to skip that also so add a `+1` so that `.Substring()` will give you the expected output for you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 Guid.Parse(string.Join("-",followActivity.Object.Split('-').Skip(1)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Or just

```
Guid.Parse(followActivity.Object.Replace("Board-",""));
```

Answer (score 1):

If the format is always the same, you could use `string.Split()`

```
Guid.Parse(followActivity.Object.Split(new char[]{'-'}, 2)[1]));
```