# How to split csv and add additional column using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, split, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a csv file and it have multiple columns. I have a specific column name called "Exported_Id" and it look something like this

```
f36b9decc73e40bfb9a6250198a83fc0/SharePoint/source_28D4CE4DFC53AABB34B41E17BE9DEBBC/item__6761c90b-c1e0-4a91-b72c-e044e5b8cc56_1.0
```

I'm just wondering how can I split to only this (Spliting before and after _ )

```
6761c90b-c1e0-4a91-b72c-e044e5b8cc56
```

and then add it to a new column call "Modified_Id" and export it with existing columns into new csv file.

I'm kinda stuck so any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
    $CSVImport = Import-CSV $Global:Advance_CSV
    foreach($CSVLine in $CSVImport){
         $CSVExportedID = $CSVLine.Exported_Id

         $Modified_Id= $CSVExportedID -split "__" 

         Select-Object $Modified_Id, "Modified_Id" | Export-Csv $ModifiedFile

    }
```

Comment: Assumed the structure of the cell content is consistent you can split the cell content with `($CSVExportedID -split "_")[-2]` on the underlines and pick the seccond to last element of the resulting array.

Comment: @Olaf It work and thank you so much. Can you also help me on how can create a new column and export it to a new csv file with existing columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a calculated property to extend your existing data set

```
$Result=
foreach($CSVLine in $CSVImport){
    $CSVLine | 
        Select-Object -Property *,
            @{
                Name = 'Modified_Id'; 
                Expression = {($_.Exported_Id -split "_")[-2]}
            }
}
$Result |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this [nice regex](https://regex101.com/r/17ibqf/1) adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11040993/15339544) to capture the [Guid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid?view=net-6.0) on that column and create a new column using a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2) with [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$re = [regex] '(?i)[0-9a-f]{8}-(?:[0-9a-f]{4}-){3}[0-9a-f]{12}'

Import-CSV path\to\myCsv.csv | Select-Object *, @{
    Name       = 'Modified_Id'
    Expression = { $re.Match($_.Exported_Id).Value }
} | Export-Csv path\to\theNewCsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```